# Windows 8 slide out functionality from desktop

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, desktop

Is there a way to have my windows 8 app slide out to the right as an overlay on top of the desktop if the user has selected the app from the desktop. So it opens as normal from metro but if the user is on the win 8 desktop you just get a smaller version. I know currently you can lock a app in to the side but I find the functionality on a desktop a bit cumbersome.

I would like to have the ability for the desktop users to quickly navigate between the desktop and app with the option to slide back out of view and an option to go to the full screen app.

this functionality, I think is useful for apps like NoteOne or notepad where a user would like a piece of information to complement the work currently being done on the desktop without having to switch between app views

possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible as far as I know. You need to use the Windows 8 split view mode.